# Data is not updating with React Hook useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a little web application that uses axios to fetch some orders from the API. My problem is the new orders only appear when the page is refreshed, they do not update automatically.

Here is my useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    apiClient
      .getEvents()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setOrders(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

And here is where I use axios:

```
import axios from "axios";

const username = "user";
const password = "pass";

const token = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`, "utf8").toString("base64");

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "API URL",
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Basic ${token}`,
  },
});

export default {
  getEvents() {
    return apiClient.get("/orders");
  },
  getEvent(order_id) {
    return apiClient.get("/orders/" + order_id);
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of the component using the `useEffect`? It would be better if we could see how the component is declaring "data" and using it.

Comment: This is my full component code: https://jsfiddle.net/1nv7bjek/2/

Comment: Does `console.log(res)` log what you expect? Is the page stuck "loading", or does the `setLoading(false);` stop that? Can you be more specific about what data isn't updating?

Comment: The data is loading on initial load of the website, but whenever I make a new order, I need to refresh the page in order to make the new order appear.

Comment: Hi,  an observation about one line, you setLoading(false) only in then block, I recommend you to add finally block and setLoading(false) inside it. In case of error loading still be true

Comment: Where is the code to make a new order? The code in the snippet (and jsfiddle), the effect runs only when the component mounts and I don't see anything trying to add more data. SO, IMO, of course you need to reload the page to refetch data.

Comment: Here is an example, I am making a new order and it doesn't adds to the left https://gyazo.com/67f15c536af6841514af07c9d3d27e2f

Comment: The data is added through a WooCommerce website, I am just fetching stuff from their Database

Comment: So how would your app know data was added somewhere else out on *some* website?

Comment: I am connected to the WooCommerce API, that's what I am currently fetching

Comment: I am using this: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders

Comment: Is the `useEffect` code correct? Doesn't `getEvents()` return the  `apiClient`? But in useEffect you're calling `apiClient.getEvents()`

Comment: I have a file called EventServices.js that contains all the axios code showed above. Then in my component I just import that apiClient since it is exported from EventServices.js

Comment: So I guess the question then is: When a new order is made in the woocommerce system, how do you indicate to the above component it needs to refetch data?

Comment: It is not supposed to update the State with the new order? or I am missing something else?

Comment: Typically the pattern you want is an app that would utilize a larger application-level state-management system, like redux or the react's Context API, and when an order is created in one part of the app it can dispatch updates to app state, and any other components can subscribe to those updates and update accordingly. You'd want to fetch the order when the app loads, and the component above just waits for order updates from app state.

Comment: As far as I know, React is supposed to update the state automatically when it changes right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When state or props update the component rerenders. Other than fetching data when it mounts, nothing else (from what I see in your fiddle) updates state (invokes `setOrders` or `setLoading`).

Comment: Then it is not possible just to update the state with the new order without using Redux or Context Api?

Comment: An easy (hackish?) lo-tech solution could be to setup an interval and just poll the backend for updates (up to you to tune how often to poll), but yeah, more sophisticated solutions typically involve a pub/sub pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem ist the useEffect-Hook itself.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    apiClient
      .getEvents()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setOrders(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

You pass an empty array as the second argument here: `}, []);`. **When you pass an empty array as second argument to `useEffect`, it will only run on first mount and then never again.**

You can pass different variables in this parameter. In this case, `useEffect` will run, when of these variables change their value. So, for example, you could have a "Refresh" button which changes a state called `refresh` which you then pass as a second argument to `useEffect`.

```
const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if(!refresh) return;
    setLoading(true);
    apiClient
      .getEvents()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setOrders(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
        setRefresh(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [refresh]);
```

Just a simple example, it could be done better, of course.

Also, one hint: You can omit the second parameter, the dependency array, of `useEffect`, which would make it run on every update of your component. **Don't do this.** In most cases, you will end up in an infinite loop because most of the time you will update the state and cause the component to rerender within `useEffect` - in your case, using `setLoading()` would be enough.